# Activating/Adding a button to tinyMCE

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I am unfortunately lost, I am trying to install an image upload plugin to my tinyMCE editor and after some research I chose : http://justboil.me/tinymce-images-plugin/

I followed the instructions and added the folder to my tinyMCE plugin directory, configured my settings with the config.php file but when it comes to activating it and adding the button in tinyMCE I am lost.

The site talks about using this code somewhere but I even with some research i still cannot find what I need to do, could anyone point me is to where I would add the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
theme : "advanced",
relative_urls : false,
plugins : "jbimages",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "jbimages,|"
// Other TinyMCE options
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the *config.php* file you mention contains the tinyMCE configuration parameters, then all you need to do is add **jbimages** to one of your *theme_advanced_buttons* config items in the position on the toolbar where you want it to appear.

If however the *config.php* file doesn't contain the full TinyMCE configuration, then it would appear whoever integrated TinyMCE into your application has hidden that functionality and you will need to talk to them or tell us what product you are using TinyMCE in.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared things up I was under the impression that that above script needed to go somewhere within the tinyMCE folder but instead it simply required me adding the correctly lines on the webpage that contained the editor.